# running a javascript code while in background android

Tags: javascript, android, background, progressive-web-apps

The platform I am targeting are those android kiosks that are connected to power 24/7. I am trying to run a PWA script in the background for extended periods of time while the user has other applications in the foreground. Are there any special flags for chrome/firefox/opera or any special browser that allows this background service sandbox functionality?

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work.  Android aggressively kills apps that aren't in the foreground.  The web browser included.  It's just not going to reliably run once the user backgrounds it.